# Difference between M and A in Xcode 5.0.2

Tags: xcode

I'm currently using Xcode 5.0.2.I noticed that when i create a model file and group the model flies in project navigation on right side of the model name greyish letter 'A' and on the right side of the project name greyish 'M' appeared.

[image: illustration]

Can anybody please tell me what is the meaning of 'A' and 'M'? Why does it appear when i create a model group?Thanks!

Comment: **Modified** and **Added**, for source control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This relates to source control.

Answer (score 0):

`M` means modified since last commit, `A` means added since last commit.

Answer (score 0):

It is source control's marks. "A" - appended. "M" - modified.